# use jQuery attribute selector in $(this) context

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm trying to check a if a href contains 'http://' by trying to check the href in the 'this' context

```
$('a').on('click',function(){
    if($('[href*="http://"]',this).length)>0){
        // so stuff
});
```

This is nog working. What is the right way of doing this?

Comment: You could do `$(this).attr('href')` to get the value. But you would then have to use a regex or something to see if `http://` is in the returned string.

Comment: I'm curious if it works in the 'this' content.

Comment: Yes it would.. see here. https://jsfiddle.net/xxwzn72d/. But you would still have to do some work with the string to see if it contains `http://`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This syntax `($('[href*="http://"]',this)` is equivalent to `$(this).find('[href*="http://"]')` - which you don't want, you want to check the current clicked `a` for that string - just check the current `href`

```
$('a').on('click',function(){
    if (this.href.indexOf("http://") > -1) {

    }
});
```